# Error processing row 1: TypeError: openai.createCompletion is not a function

Tags: summarization

I am trying to summarize chat transcripts in an excel file. It shows error for the following code:

```
    `// Iterate over rows array using a for...of loop to maintain async/await context
        for (let { row, rowNumber } of rows) {
          let chatText = row.getCell(1).value;
          if (chatText) { // Ensure there's text to summarize
            try {
              **const response = await openai.createCompletion({**
                model: "text-davinci-003",
                prompt: `Summarize this chat: ${chatText}`,
                max_tokens: 100,
              });
              let summary = response.data.choices[0].text.trim();
              row.getCell(2).value = summary; // Assign the summary to the next column
            } catch (apiError) {
              console.error(`Error processing row ${rowNumber}:`, apiError);
            }`
```

Exepctation was that the rows in my excel sheet can be summarized using the openai api.